# Creating raster from point values

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

I have a raster whose pixel values are `0` or `1` (b/w areas in the image below) and data type is `Float32`.

I made a point layer from each individual pixel's center. Then I made some calculation for all points and added it as new field.

[image]

How can I make a new raster, which has the same properties (resolution, pixel size, data type, etc.)  with the first raster, from those point values?

Comment: Have you tried `gdal_rasterize` yet?: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html

Comment: @Aaron my ultimate goal is to assign point values to existing pixels. Since I want to try another ways, I have asked the question this way. I couldn't use `gdal_proximity`. I'm getting errors. But  It looks like I will try to solve my problem by writing code instead of fixing errors.

Comment: +1 for `gdal_rasterize` which is available as the [Rasterize](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster) tool in the QGIS Processing toolbox.  You can specify the same extent and cellsize as your existing raster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would be the complete work-flow (as partially mentioned already by @Aaron and @user2856):

1. make a copy of your original raster (so that extent, resolution, CRS etc. remain the same)
2. use GDAL > Vector Conversion > ['Rasterize (Overwrite With Attribute)'](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-overwrite-with-attribute) tool (`gdal:rasterize_over`) to overwrite the raster's values with the values from your shapefile

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of is the inverse distance weighting (IDW) algorithm.

If you're having difficulty understanding the algorithm then this tutorial should help you out.

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html

Comment: The rasterize of processing might be better, since it will honour a one to one value (burn) a new value and not do an interpolation.

Comment: That's very true. But in a situation where you want the output raster  resolution to be higher than the original raster resolution then IDW might be a better option. Someone might find this useful.